# C++ Thread does not detect global variable change

Tags: c++, multithreading, global-variables, mutex

I have 2 threads monitoring the same global `state`, if the `state.shutdown` becomes `false`, the thread `run()` should return.  The code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

struct State {
    bool shutdown = false;

    ~State() {
        shutdown = true;
    }
};

State state;

#define CHECK_SHUTDOWN     \
  {                        \
    std::cout << (state.shutdown ? " SHUTDOWN " : " NOSHUT ") << typeid(*this).name() << std::endl; \
    if (state.shutdown) {  \
        return;            \
    }                      \
  }

class Mythread {
public:
    void join();
    void run();
    void launch();
    std::thread self_thread;
};

void Mythread::run() {
    while(1) {
        CHECK_SHUTDOWN
    }
}

void Mythread::join() {
    if (self_thread.joinable()) {
        self_thread.join();
    }
}

void Mythread::launch() {
    self_thread = std::thread(&Mythread::run, this);
}

std::mutex mtx;
void shut() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);   
    state.shutdown = true;
}

int main()
{
    Mythread thread1;
    Mythread thread2;

    thread1.launch();
    thread2.launch();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));


    //state.shutdown = true;
    shut(); //This makes no difference with the line above

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();


    return 0;
}
```

However, even I manually set the `state.shutdown` to be true, the threads can never detect it. I got prints like:

```
 NOSHUT 8Mythread                                                                                                
 NOSHUT 8Mythread                                                                                                
 NOSHUT 8Mythread                                                                                                                                                                                                                

...Program finished with exit code 0                                                                             
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

at the end. I'm also confused given that the `run()` function is never returned, the threads join should hang. However the threads can join successfully.

Any help would be very appreciated here!

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful topic of "sequencing", which is a set of rules that specifies how threads "see" changes to objects from other threads. This requires specific, explicit action to be taken by ***both*** threads, the thread that changed an object, and a thread that "sees" the object. The rules are complex, and cannot be fully summarized in one or two paragraphs on stackoverflow.com, unless greatly oversimplified and leaving out a bunch of details. If you really want to learn this subject properly, see your C++ textbook's lengthy discussion of the subject matter.

Comment: The simple fix would be to make `State::shutdown` an [`std::atomic<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) but you would be well-served by following Sam's advice and reading up on _why_ this is necessary.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for your reply. Could you kindly point to me any online resources? I could not find it in my C++ primer book(4th edition).

Comment: You need [a more advanced C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a [data race](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races) on shutdown.

> When an evaluation of an expression writes to a memory location and another evaluation reads or modifies the same memory location, the expressions are said to conflict. A program that has two conflicting evaluations has a data race [...]

In `shut()` you set the `shutdown` flag using a mutex, but the check is performed *without* the mutex (and the `State` destructor doesn't use a mutex either). Thus you have conflicting operations (read + write) on a non-atomic variable, without the proper happens before relation. This is a data race which results in undefined behavior.

The simple solution would be to make `shutdown` an `std::atomic<bool>`, then you wouldn't even need the mutex to set the flag.

For more details about data races and the C++ memory model I can recommend this paper which I have co-authored: [Memory Models for C/C++ Programmers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04432)